# Gaining access to a folder which requires you to be the admin/owner?

Tags: permissions, files, folder, administrator

Hey there, I'm trying to install a gedit plugin called [zoom](https://github.com/dinkel/gedit-zoom/downloads/), and in order for it to be picked up by gedit it needs to be extracted in this folder
    `/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins`.

My problem is I can't copy paste the files into that directory. I tried changing the permissions on that folder but it says "You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissons".

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply copy the file using the command line.

> sudo cp SOURCEFILE DESTINATION

This will run `cp` as root.

Comment: Why can't we just use the File Manager, @Octavian? This shouldn't be necessary. If Terminal allows a "non-owner" to perform this action - then there is no logical reason why File Manager cannot allow a "non-owner" to perform this action.

Comment: There is. You should read up on [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/sudo.8.html).