# Can I open .debs with Synaptic in 11.10?

Tags: software-center

Ubuntu Software Center is very slow here.Seriously, Windows virtual machines run faster that that here!

I dislike Software Center so I installed Synaptic ages ago, and that loads in 2 seconds! Perfect. Well almost - I can't seem to open downloaded .debs with it. Can I change things so that Synaptic opens .debs by default?

Is it possible to remove Software Center completely and replace it with Synaptic?

Comment: You open debs with Gdebi not with Synaptic..

Comment: Try deepin software centre .It is much better than ubuntu software centre .It have an built in update manager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You open downloaded debs with `gdebi`

It is not installed by default, so use this command to do so

`sudo apt-get install gdebi`

To make it default for deb handling, follow these steps

Right click on any .deb file and click properties

[image]

Go to the Open With Tab

[image]

Select Gdebi Package Installer and click Set as default

[image]

As for software center, you can safely remove it by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
```

and you can use synaptic for the GUI installation of packages from the repos

Comment: Thank you Amith KK. And thank you to everyone for the most helpful and interesting replies.

Comment: @dunderhead no problem. That's what the community is for :)

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question - for installing a .deb file I personally prefer the command line by executing `sudo dpkg -i file.deb`. It's much faster than both Software Center and Synaptic and you can install multiple packages at once (e.g.  `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`).

You can remove Software Center but why would you? Leave it there and don't use it. Sometimes I find it very useful for searching for an application I need and see its ratings.

Comment: The trouble with `dpkg` is that it does absolutely no dependency resolution and can result in broken packages. `gdebi` is much better IMO, and has a CLI tool too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install packages by synaptic that already downloaded, You can use this method, You can copy the downloaded packages to the **/var/cache/apt/archive** directory. Then open synaptic and search for your package and install it. However you can't copy anything to that directory unless you are the owner of the directory (You may be the administrator but not the root) then you have to make permissions (I usually log into the root account and copy those packages) you can copy packages through the terminal. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104964/need-owner-permissions-for-root-folder) link for changing permissions, below screen-shot is the permissions tab of the Archive Folder

[image]